Using FeePayer on web3 solana token swap?
I am using javascript from github to create a solana SPL token swap, but I want to use feepayer to pay the transaction fee, I am a beginner, can you explain how to implement it? I have attached the script code and the original github link. Thank you for your help.
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
import bs58 from "bs58";
import { SolanaTracker } from "../";

async function swap() {
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    bs58.decode(
      "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE"
    )
  );
  const solanaTracker = new SolanaTracker(
    keypair,
    "https://rpc.solanatracker.io/public?advancedTx=true"
  );

  const swapResponse = await solanaTracker.getSwapInstructions(
    "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112", // From Token
    "4k3Dyjzvzp8eMZWUXbBCjEvwSkkk59S5iCNLY3QrkX6R", // To Token
    0.0001, // Amount to swap
    "auto", // Slippage
    keypair.publicKey.toBase58(), // Payer public key
    "auto", // Priority fee (Recommended while network is congested)
  );

  // Jito transaction
  try {
    const txid = await solanaTracker.performSwap(swapResponse, {
      sendOptions: { skipPreflight: true },
      confirmationRetries: 30,
      confirmationCheckInterval: 500,
      commitment: "processed",
      jito: {
        enabled: true,
        tip: 0.0001,
      },
    });
    // Returns txid when the swap is successful or throws an error if the swap fails
    console.log("Transaction ID:", txid);
    console.log("Transaction URL:", `https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);
  } catch (error: any) {
    const {signature, message} = error;
    console.error("Error performing swap:", message, signature);
  }
}

swap();


As an example, feePayer for SOL transfer:
const { Keypair, Connection, SystemProgram, Transaction, sendAndConfirmTransaction } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const bs58 = require("bs58").default || require("bs58");

async function transferSol() {
  console.log("[1] Generating keypairs...");
  const userKeypair = Keypair.generate(); // User sending SOL
  const feePayerKeypair = Keypair.generate(); // Fee payer for the transaction
  console.log("User Keypair Secret Key:", bs58.encode(userKeypair.secretKey));
  console.log("Fee Payer Keypair Secret Key:", bs58.encode(feePayerKeypair.secretKey));

  console.log("[2] Initializing Solana connection...");
  const connection = new Connection("https://solana-mainnet.core.chainstack.com/07a6c79904cc54ed57358287a01000b4");

  console.log("[3] Defining recipient and transfer amount...");
  const recipientPublicKey = Keypair.generate().publicKey; // Generate a random recipient
  const transferAmount = 0.1 * 1e9; // 0.1 SOL in lamports

  console.log("[4] Creating transfer instruction...");
  const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: userKeypair.publicKey,
    toPubkey: recipientPublicKey,
    lamports: transferAmount,
  });

  console.log("[5] Creating transaction and setting fee payer...");
  let transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);
  transaction.feePayer = feePayerKeypair.publicKey;

  console.log("[6] Sending transaction...");
  try {
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [feePayerKeypair, userKeypair], // Sign with both user and fee payer
      {
        skipPreflight: true,
        commitment: "processed"
      }
    );

    console.log("Transaction successful! Signature:", signature);
    console.log("Transaction URL:", `https://solscan.io/tx/${signature}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending transaction:", error);
    if (error.message.includes("insufficient funds")) {
      console.error("The fee payer does not have enough SOL to cover the transaction fee.");
    }
  }
}

// Execute the function
transferSol();

